# How can I attach an image file in printwriter to send via socket?

Tags: android, sockets, printwriter

Here is my code:

```
StringBuilder sb_other = new StringBuilder();
sb_other.append(String.format("%-10s%-10s","\t","My text to print"));
sb_other.append("\t\n");
Socket sockKitchen = new Socket("192.168.1.102",9100);
PrintWriter oStream = new PrintWriter(sockKitchen.getOutputStream());
oStream.println(sb_other);
oStream.flush();
oStream.close();
sockKitchen.close();
```

How can I attach an image file in printwriter to send via socket?

Comment: You can't. A `PrintWriter` is for character data. Image files are binary. You should use an `OutputStream`.

Comment: How can I print using OutputStream.

Comment: @MrithunTP Did u get answer ?

Comment: @byteC0de Sorry.I didn't received any proper method to solve it.

Comment: Did u get answer for  thermal printer ?